# Unable to select children element of tag <li> in tab of website

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am using the below VB code on internet explorer to automate a web portal:

```
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplore
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim myURL As String

Dim htmlInput As HTMLInputElement
Dim htmlColl As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim p As String
Dim link As Object
Dim I As Integer
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
myURL = "url............."
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate myURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a").Item(7).Click    <-----Error

Err_Clear:
  If Err <> 0 Then
  Err.Clear
  Resume Next
  End If
```

But it gives an error on the highlighted line and below is my web inspects:

[image]
Please guide me where i am making a mistake to simply click on tab? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put a doevents into your page loading loop.

```
Do
    doevents 
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
```

Get the li element by id then the child anchor within.

```
HTMLDoc.getElementById("current").getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
```

Comment: I really thankful to your guidance and get direct solution by your single respond, God gives you more success in your this knowledge and leads you to the right path. :)